# The SEO Framework не выводятся символы в мета тегах к отдельным страница wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на wordpress с плагином The SEO Framework. Когда к записи в блог заполняют мета теги и ставят символы - всё окей, они выводятся в дискрипшн.

Когда ставят символы к отдельным страницам - символы пропадают

Здесь символы есть. Это запись блога

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь их нет. Они сами пропадают. Это отдельная страница сайта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы символы везде выводились?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна кодировка для таблицы `wp_postmeta` `uninicode_utf8mb_520ci`. Но лучше сделайте ее для всех таблиц и в `wp-config.php` для кодировки укажите нужную.